# What's the best way to manage read/unread items (NoSQL/SQL)?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, nosql

I'm going to build a Symfony 2.1 application which needs to know the state of items (read/unread), are there any efficient methods to save item states (with many items) ? Using SQL relationnal table stay the best choice ? Or maybe a NoSQL database like MongoDB is a better idea for handling read/unread status ?

Comment: Are your objects consider read when one person reads it, or can the state be tracked separately per user?

Comment: Yes the state be tracked separately per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to manage this accurately (i.e. without cutting corners) is an associative table. Assuming your database contains **items** and **users**, build another table as follows:

```
item_users (id, user_id, item_id, time_added)
```

Any field present in there (combination of user and item) is treated as "the user has read this". This will generate a lot of data, but can be dealt with pretty easily by clever indexing/sharding. For example:

- If you have a lot of users and a lot of items, sharding by users is probably the best
- If you are often interested in who has read a certain post, sharding by item is also worth it
- Consider indexing both user_id and index_id separately (INDEX + FOREIGN KEY and cascade on both UPDATE and DELETE)

This will allow you to very easily query the table. Bear in mind that your data might get big if you have lots of users and posts, at which point sharding really becomes necessary.

Comment: What's the `id` column going to do for you?

Comment: Allows you to delete more conveniently? The id field is a personal preference in this case.